# Changing web hosting companies

Tags: domains, web-hosting

I currently have a website with a company who I am not happy with. I have managed to do my own website on a website building company.

How do I get that website onto my current domain? What information will I need from the other company and do I just have to give them notice? They only host it for me with an annual charge.

Answer (score 3):

If you're just changing web hosting companies but your domain will stay the same, then follow these steps:

1). Upload all of your content from the previous web hosting account to your new web hosting account (including any server-side applications, database, etc...).

2). Update the [nameservers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_server) with your DNS provider to point to the nameservers used by your new web hosting company.

If you created custom nameservers (often referred to as "Vanity Nameservers") (e.g., `ns1.yourdomain.com` and `ns2.yourdomain.com`) that were hosted with your previous hosting company, then you'll need to create new ones with your new web hosting company (contact their support or check their knowledebase/FAQ on how to do this).

3). Update any `A` records in your DNS table to point the IP address of your new web hosting account so that your domain (and any subdomains like `www`) point to this IP address.

4.) Verify that your website is reachable as it was before, and that the following are accessible (if you use them):

- Email accounts
- FTP accounts
- SSL (if used, this will need to be re-provisioned for the IP address of your new hosting account)

If anything is not working, contact the technical team of your new web hosting company for migration assistance.

5.) Since you paid annually, you might request a prorated refund, but leave the previous account active for one week during the transition to the new web hosting company. If you cannot obtain a refund, then you might just remove the content there after one week.

Comment: DOn't forget to recreate all your email addresses